# SSRS Textbox hide bullet point

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a textbox with a list of bullet points. All of the bullet points except for the last one are static text that always appears.

The last bullet point is also static text but it only appears when a parameter is true.

So when it's true I want to see:

> 1. Some Text
> 2. Some other Text
> 3. Some more text
> 4. Final line of text

when it's false I want to see:

> 1. Some Text
> 2. Some other Text
> 3. Some more text

I tried setting the value of the final bullet point to be an expression which hides the text if the parameter is false, but that gives me:

> 1. Some Text
> 2. Some other Text
> 3. Some more text
> 4. 

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but how do I hide the last bullet point?

Comment: Alternatively if there is a way to renumber bullet points, I could put point 4 in a separate text box which shows and hides. Can you set the start number of bullet points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but a work around:

Ended up getting rid of bullet points completely and manually numbering the items in the list. Then turned the last one into an expression which only displayed when certain criteria was true.

Feel there should be a better way but not able to find one (if you can provide a better answer I'm still very interested)